# Syntax for accessing sub-buckets in Vega-lite

Tags: vega-lite

`datum.by_func.buckets.reserved_sum.value` caught error message `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')`. What is the correct syntax of accessing the value of `reserved_sum` and `consumed_sum`? I tried `datum.by_func.buckets.reserved_sum`, no error but value returned as zero. I'd like to use the value to create line chart.

Here's the sample aggregations data.

```
  "aggregations": {
"by_workweek": {
  "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
  "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
  "buckets": [
    {
      "key": "24ww05",
      "doc_count": 872,
      "by_func": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "R",
            "doc_count": 275,
            "reserved_sum": {
              "value": 943998
            },
            "consumed_sum": {
              "value": 177610.0602690503
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "E",
            "doc_count": 189,
            "reserved_sum": {
              "value": 213391
            },
            "consumed_sum": {
              "value": 65354.019666539505
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "key": "24ww06",
      "doc_count": 2023,
      "by_func": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "E",
            "doc_count": 483,
            "reserved_sum": {
              "value": 687149
            },
            "consumed_sum": {
              "value": 338574.3589058537
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "R",
            "doc_count": 420,
            "reserved_sum": {
              "value": 520497
            },
            "consumed_sum": {
              "value": 177946.58002144098
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
}
```

Comment: Please provide a working example in vega editor so we can debug.